# How to display split strings in JOptionpane by user's split size

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

Hi how can I display my Split Strings in JOptionPane? My window keeps printing/showing my strings 1 by 1 , I want them to print/show  given my user's split size

```
    String letters, splitSize;

    letters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter String: ");
    final int numInLetters = letters.length(); 

    splitSize = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Split Size");
    int sizeSplit = Integer.parseInt(splitSize);

    if (numInLetters % sizeSplit == 0) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Given String is" + letters);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Split String are: ");

        String []in_array;

        in_array = letters.split("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= in_array.length; i++) {


                    //what alternative way to show my split string here given by user's split size
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, in_array[i-1]);         


         if (i % sizeSplit == 0) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
```

Comment: Create a JComponent that looks the way you want and pass it as the message argument to JOptionPane

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I think this might be what you want:

```
String letters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter String: ");

String splitSize  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Split Size");
int sizeSplit = Integer.parseInt(splitSize);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
int idx = 0;
while (idx < letters.length()) {
    int toIdx = Math.min(idx + sizeSplit, letters.length());
    list.add(letters.substring(idx, toIdx));
    idx = toIdx;
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Split String are: " + System.lineSeparator() + String.join(System.lineSeparator(), list));
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan I tried executing your code for me to test however in 'JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Split String are: " System.lineSeparator() + String.join(System.lineSeparator(), list)); ' it shows "The method lineSeparator() is undefined for the type String" how can I fix this please, sorry I'm new to this method

Comment: There was a missing +, try it now.  Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.